# Regex to find string where parenthesis are not closed

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, regular-language

I need a regex to find strings where parenthesis are not closed

**Example:**

```
02 Back for Good (Radio Mix.mp3
```

Find "(Radio Mix"

**But if**

```
02 Back for Good (Radio Mix).mp3
```

Must find nothing

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: I wonder how you can "program" the regex engine to find the places where a closing bracket should be.

Comment: a regex like this might work [Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/fU4eV8/3)

Comment: Thanks @benjaminS its work

Comment: I'll post it as answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to capture up until the file extension, you can do this:

```
\([^\)]*(?=\.\w+$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/cB1jG2/1

It looks for an opening bracket followed by anything *except* a closing bracket, and then a *positive lookahead* to find a file extension at the end of the string.

If you know the possible file extensions, you can be more literal:

```
\([^\)]*(?=\.(?:wav|mp3)$)
```

And if you can have nested parentheses, this can match some cases, **but not all** and can probably be reduced to something cleaner:

```
\((?:\([^\(\)]*?\)|[^\)])*(?=\.\w+$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aQ1eO3/1

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
preg_match('/\(.+\)$/','02 Back for Good (Radio Mix.mp3');
```

- `\(` matches a literal `(`.
- `.+` matches one or more characters.
- `\)$` matches a literal `)` a the end of the string.

Thus the whole expression matches from the first opening parentheses to the last closing parentheses if it's the last character in the string. Otherwise, it will not match.

Comment: Thanks for your help but its on the other direction that I need. Find (Radio Mix.mp3 only if there is not parenthesis at the end

Comment: @DavidZeller check the updated answer. hope this will help.

Comment: While this regex may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Mariano Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Following Regex captures the desired output:

```
(\([\w\s]+).mp3
```

A working example can be [**found on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/fU4eV8/3).

It searches for an opened parenthesis -**\(**-, captures the words/digits(**\w**) and whitspaces(**\s**) and appends the file extension "**mp3**" - that way, the closing parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is trying with 2 reg-ex, and counting that the amount of parenthesis groups is the same than `(` or `)` so in this case, you are safe for all cases:

```
const value = <titleToCheck>;
const allParenthesisAreCorrect =
 (value.match(/\(.*?\)/g) || []).length !==
    (value.match(/\(/g) || []).length ||
 (value.match(/\(.*?\)/g) || []).length !== 
    (value.match(/\)/g) || []).length;
```